# What is the meaning of 震えてら?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 震えてら and how is it different from 震えている?

Answer (score 3):

> 震えてら。

The ～てら(あ) ending is [this](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A6%E3%82%89%E3%81%82/#jn-152635):

> てらあ の解説
> ［連語］《「ている」に終助詞「わ」の付いた「ているわ」の音変化》「ている」の意を感動的に、また、とがめたりさげすんだりする口調で表す。…ているなあ。…ているよ。「あんなにきれいに咲いてらあ」「そんなこと知ってらあ」
> [補説]ガ・ナ・バ・マ行の五段活用動詞に付く場合は「でらあ」となる。また「てら」と約してもいう。「鳥が飛んでらあ」「あんなこと言ってら」

It can add an emotional, despising, or reproaching tone to a sentence ending 「～ている。」. To me, it sounds pretty old-fashioned, and I think it's probably heard/used more in Kanto region than here in Kansai region. It can be pronounced/written 「てらあ。」「てらぁ。」 or 「てら。」